# What to do about damaged bike frame

Tags: frames, repair

I recently bought a used bike from a police auction that had a nasty cut in the frame (presumably caused by a angle grinder or something similar). Should I be worried about the bike's structural rigidity? If so, what should I do to mend the frame? I thought about wrapping a piece of aluminum around the damaged area and bolting it down with metal ties, but I'm not sure how much that'd help.

[image]

Comment: If it is a steel frame  (and it should be, given the brand name), my best bet is to weld a piece of a steel tube of a slightly bigger diameter. given that the damage does not cut through the whole thing, maybe simply welding a half-tube on top of it will suffice. In any case, repainting will be needed, and the whole frame aesthetics would be compromised if no clever design decision is made to conceal the repair.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but unfortunately I don't have access to any welding tools. Would JB weld or something similar work the same?

Comment: The correct thing to do would be a tube replacement by a framebuilder but it will probably more expensive than the price you've paid for the bike and need a strip down, repaint and rebuild.

Comment: YIkes...I'm only planning on using this bike for about 3 more years (through university). Is there any cost effective way (preferably under $30) for me to fix that up? Assuming I don't crash the bike into anything, would the damage affect the structural rigidity by a whole lot?

Comment: There's no such thing as "only three years". Even at a mile a day, three years is still over a thousand miles in which any pothole that you don't notice until you're on top of it could become a fatal accident.

Comment: Got it-I've decided to scrap the bike for parts and get myself a new frame. Thanks for your help

Comment: This will sound like an add but its not, i have no affiliation with the company, The cheapest solution would be to use a product called fiber fix and wrap the crap out of it. Its a product you dip in water and then wrap things and it hardens, use enough of it and it is insanely strong. even then i would probably just try and find someone who could weld a patch on for you. if you look around im sure you could find someone that would do it for a 12 pack with some scrap material.

Comment: Or some JB weld. But honestly, it doesn't look that bad to me. Take it apart and jump up and down on the frame. If you can't intentionally break it, and it doesn't even bend, then put it back together. The one thing I do agree with is that, that bike's still got over a thousand miles in it, no problem. Working brakes, derail-er, etc.? And you're complaining about a little slit in the frame? You must not dumpster dive for bikes very often. She's a keeper ;)

Comment: @Mazura So, you're proposing to take a dangerously broken frame, subject it to physical stress and then use it as a bike? That's a really terrible idea.

Comment: If you cannot weld, or if the frame is aluminium, inject high density  polyurethane insulator into the tube and let it expand fully and harden for a few days. This will add a lot of structural strength to the damaged tube. Then trim off any excess, use an angle grinder or orbital sander to rough up the surface around the cut and use a metal-filled epoxy like Liquid Steel or Smooth-On Metalset A4 over the cut generously. Roll a piece of 1/8 aluminum on top and fasten with hose clamps. Generously coat everything in epoxy and let it set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally would not ride that bike. The top tube is severely compromised now, it will get worse as cracks develop from the ends of the cuts.

No-one plans to crash so you can't resolve to always ride it 'gently', You do not want to ride over a pothole or off a curb and have the top tube buckle up into your face, neck or chest.

Your proposed fix of clamping a sheet of aluminium over the tube would not be sufficient, neither will JB weld. There is no safe solution for $30.

Unfortunately, a proper welding job will probably cost more than you paid for the bike.

Comment: IMHO it was unethical for the police to sell such a thing except with the express mention for 'parts use only' and maybe cut through both top and down tubes to render it unusable.

Comment: I agree, *especially* if it was connected with a police force that is charged with maintaining public safety. I imagine all the bikes were sold 'as-is' and 'at the buyer's risk'.

Comment: Ah well that's a bummer. Thanks for your help! (Side note: it's possible the police had "sold as is". I can't exactly remember--got too excited and didn't pay too much attention to the bike when I got it)

Comment: Sorry man. You'll just have to chalk that up as a lesson in buying used bikes - always inspect what you are considering buying very carefully. Suggest you start looking for a bike with busted wheels or drivetrain, but a good frame.

Comment: Yeah, it was definitely my inexperience that got me there. Thanks for advice

Comment: Now you are slightly less inexperienced, young padawan

Comment: @ks794 I suggest you buy a second bike, perhaps with naffed/missing running gear, and look to make one good out of both.